# what are the delegate methods available with uibutton

Tags: iphone

In UITextField we have some delegate methods like that any delegate method available in UIButton

can any one tell me those mehods

UIButton Class Reference

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`UIButton` does not make use of the delegation design pattern. There is no `UIButtonDelegate` protocol nor `UIButton` declares a `delegate` property.

`UIButton`  uses the Target-Action design pattern through the methods inherited from [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) to send action messages to a target object.

Answer (score 2):

UIButton doesn't have a delegate. You can listen to specific actions by implementing custom methods. You can add a selector for the controlEvents listed [in the documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl)

Answer (score 1):

There are no delegate methods available with `UIButton`, it doesn't have any `delegate` property.