# Is UIButton have any delegate methods?

Tags: ios, delegates, uibutton

In UITableview we have some delegate methods like that any delegate method available in UIButton

can any one tell me those mehods

Comment: There are no delegate methods for UIbutton. You can refer to the class docuementstion to confirm that. You will normally configure event handlers for events such as `touchUpInside`

Comment: @ilesh , I want to know about UIbutton delegate methods

Comment: @Mannik kolhe uibutton has no delegate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UIButton** does not have any delegate methods. You can listen to specific actions by implementing custom methods.

This question is already ask for more details please refer [Best Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6834762/4527240)