# Uncaught Exception in Button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a uiview with a couple of elements that I use for a comment function in my app. There is a text field, button, and line separator. Everything renders fine however when I click submit the app crashes and I get this error.

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe58c459620'
```

I don't see anything wrong with my implementation so this error is a little confusing to me. This is the class for my UIView

```
import UIKit
protocol CommentInputAccessoryViewDelegate {
    func handleSubmit(for comment: String?)
}

class CommentInputAccessoryView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var delegate: CommentInputAccessoryViewDelegate?
    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

   fileprivate let submitButton: UIButton = {
        let submitButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        submitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
        submitButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        submitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSubmit), for: .touchUpInside)
        //submitButton.isEnabled = false
        return submitButton
    }()

    lazy var commentTextField: UITextField = {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "Add a comment"
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        return textField
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
       // backgroundColor = .red

        addSubview(submitButton)
        submitButton.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, right:rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 50, height: 0)
        addSubview(commentTextField)
        commentTextField.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: submitButton.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 12, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        setupLineSeparatorView()

    }
    fileprivate func setupLineSeparatorView(){
        let lineSeparatorView = UIView()
        lineSeparatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 230, green: 230, blue: 230)
        addSubview(lineSeparatorView)
        lineSeparatorView.anchor(top:topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0.5)
    }

    @objc func handleSubmit(for comment: String?){
        guard let commentText = commentTextField.text else{
            return
        }
        delegate?.handleSubmit(for: commentText)
    }

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let isCommentValid = commentTextField.text?.count ?? 0 > 0
        if isCommentValid {
            submitButton.isEnabled = true
        }else{
            submitButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
    func clearCommentTextField(){
        commentTextField.text = nil
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

This is the accompanying class that ultimately handles the submission through a protocol method

```
    //allows you to gain access to the input accessory view that each view controller has for inputting text
    lazy var containerView: CommentInputAccessoryView = {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
        let commentInputAccessoryView = CommentInputAccessoryView(frame:frame)
        commentInputAccessoryView.delegate = self
        return commentInputAccessoryView

    }()


    @objc func handleSubmit(for comment: String?){
        guard let comment = comment, comment.count > 0 else{
            return
        }

        let userText = Comments(content: comment, uid: User.current.uid, profilePic: User.current.profilePic!,eventKey: eventKey)
        sendMessage(userText)
        // will clear the comment text field
        self.containerView.clearCommentTextField()
    }

extension NewCommentsViewController {
    func sendMessage(_ message: Comments) {
        ChatService.sendMessage(message, eventKey: eventKey)

    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your `handleSubmit` func take an argument?  Your button won't be passing that argument, so it seems you should just take it out.  I don't know if that's the cause of the crash - just the first thing I see.

Comment: well the handle submit function takes a string as an argument

Comment: it is the way I make use of the protocol and submit the comment to my database

Comment: The `handleSubmit` defined in your protocol does, but the function you are calling with your button selector shouldn't.  Additionally, you are never using that argument inside that function, so you should take it out for that reason as well.

Comment: ah your right lol i feel dumb thanks @creeperspeak

Comment: Don't feel dumb!  This is why SO exists - other people will notice things you don't see.  Did this fix the crash?

Comment: yes it fixes it @creeperspeak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162628/discussion-between-ron-baker-and-creeperspeak).

Answer (score 1):

The associated method for the target/action `#selector(handleSubmit)` must be

```
@objc func handleSubmit(_ sender: UIButton) { ...
```

or

```
@objc func handleSubmit() { ...
```

Other forms are not supported.

---

Does the code compile at all?
Actually you can't use `self` in the initializer `let submitButton: UIButton = { .. }()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that UIButton doesn't have a copyWithZone method and that you can't define delegates for UIButtons:

[what are the delegate methods available with uibutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834298/what-are-the-delegate-methods-available-with-uibutton)

Comment: where did I place a delegate for a uibutton

Comment: After a (too) quick view at your code, I haven't seen your handleSubmit inside your view and thought you want to call the handleSubmit method in your delegate directly from the button. And like @creeperspeak said, don't feel dumb about it. That happens to everyone is one reason why I became a huge fan of code reviews.